# ind $\tan \alpha$ in the square

Tags: trigonometry, contest-math

[image]

let say the square has sides of 2 units, $DM = DN = AN = AP = 1$, $NP = \sqrt 2$, $NQ = QP = \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$, and $AR \ne AP$ (?)

we have know that $\tan \alpha = \frac 2{RP}$, but what's the value of RP?

let say $AR < AP$, then $2 < \tan \alpha < 4$, we left D and E.

what is the exactly the value of $\tan \alpha$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\alpha = \angle DMN + \angle NMQ,$$

where $\angle DMN = 45^\circ$ and $\tan \angle NMQ=0.5$.

Thus,

$$\tan\alpha=\frac{1+0.5}{1-(1)(0.5)}=3$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=(0,0), C=(1,1)$.  Then $M=(1/2,1), Q=(1/4,1/4), R=(1/6,0), \tan \alpha=\frac {1}{1/3}=3$

Comment: how can you determine coordinate R?

Comment: By exending $MQ$ until it hits the $x$ axis